# How to get QuerySelectField current value with Flask WTF

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

If using **SelectField** we can get the current value that prepopulate in form from database using the **`obj`** argument, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57830510/8070090) on my previous question.

For now, I want to get the current value using `QuerySelectField`.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
def course_list():
    return Course.query.all()

class PaymentForm(Form):
    total_price = IntegerField(validators=[required()])
    course_name = QuerySelectField('Course name', validators=[required()], query_factory=course_list)
    # ....
    # ....
```

And here is the route.

```
@app.route('/edit_payment/<int:payment_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_payment(payment_id):
    payment = Pament.query.filter_by(id=payment_id).first()
    course = db.session.query(Course.name).filter_by(id=payment.course_id).first()
    payment_form = PaymentForm(obj=course) # here I try to use the obj argument.
    # ... validate on submit
        # ....
        # ....
    return render_template(payment=payment, payment_form=payment_form)
```

On the route above which I call the `PaymentForm`, I try to parse the **`obj`** argument, but seems it did not prepopulate the value on current user from db.

here is how I call it on Jinja2 template:

```
{{ f.render_field(payment_form.course_name, value=payment.name) }}
```

So, the point of my question is, how to get the `QuerySelectField` value base on current user value on database..?

**EDIT**:

Here is the snippet of my model:

```
class Payment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'payment'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    course = db.relationship('Course', backref=db.backref('payment', lazy='dynamic'))
    # ...
    # ...
    def __init__(self, course):
        self.course = course

class Course(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'course'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    # ...
    # ...
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

And I also tried to pass the value on **`obj`** like this:

```
payment = Pament.query.filter_by(id=payment_id).first()
payment_form = PaymentForm(obj=payment)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this by following this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329442/8070090).

Comment: That answer is about setting a default value for QuerySelectField. How did you get the selected value to save to your db?